# Access token required for different Facebook graph versions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Why Facebook requests an access_token if I call a specific version of its API (for example https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/?fields=engagement&id=https://www.tomshw.it)

while doesn't request an access_token if I request the same endpoint without version specified (example: https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=share&id=https://www.tomshw.it)?

Thanks

Comment: It’s not the same request, you are asking for a different field here. // If you don’t specify an API version, then it falls back to the lowest one that is currently available. The `shares` field has been removed, and requesting the `engagement` of an OG object now requires an access token.